# Breaking changes with cloud_firestore 2.0?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I am using CloudFirestore with my app.
Everything was working fine and since the 2.0.0 version, I encounter errors that I didn't before.

Here is the code :

```
   final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('familyAccounts')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('users');

    final DocumentSnapshot doc1 = await _fireStore.doc('user1').get();
    final DocumentSnapshot doc2 = await _fireStore.doc('user2').get();

    final _fireStore2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('familyAccounts')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('users')
        .doc('user1')
        .collection('vocList');
    await _fireStore2.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        _carnetVoc1.add(
          VocList(
              ref: doc['ref'],
              titre: doc['titre'],
              creation: doc['dateCreation'],
              modification: doc['dateModification'],
              wordId: doc['mots']),
        );
      });
    });
    final _fireStore3 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('familyAccounts')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('users')
        .doc('user2')
        .collection('vocList');
    await _fireStore3.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        _carnetVoc2.add(
          VocList(
              ref: doc['ref'],
              titre: doc['titre'],
              creation: doc['dateCreation'],
              modification: doc['dateModification'],
              wordId: doc['mots']),
        );
      });
    });

    _accountEmail = id;

    Map user1 = doc1.data()!;
    Map user2 = doc2.data()!;

    _user1 = User(
        userId: user1['userId'],
        avatar: user1['avatar'],
        classe: user1['classe'],
        teacherCode: user1['teacherCode'],
        carnetVoc: _carnetVoc1);

    _user2 = User(
        userId: user2['userId'],
        avatar: user2['avatar'],
        classe: user2['classe'],
        teacherCode: user2['teacherCode'],
        carnetVoc: _carnetVoc2);
```

The lines :
Map user1 = doc1.data()!;
Map user2 = doc2.data()!;
no longer work with the new version : I get this :

"A value of type object can't be assigned to a variable of type Map".

I don't understand what has changed... as all this was working fine before.

Anyone encountered this too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a document to perform the migration: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/

Referring to it, you should add type `<Map<String, dynamic>>` explicitly.

In your case you need to change:

```
    final DocumentSnapshot doc1 = await _fireStore.doc('user1').get();
    final DocumentSnapshot doc2 = await _fireStore.doc('user2').get();
```

to:

```
    final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> doc1 = await _fireStore.doc('user1').get();
    final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> doc2 = await _fireStore.doc('user2').get();
```

Also, `cloud_firestore: 2.0.0` promotes type safety, hence I'd suggest you using Map concrete types for your variables:

```
    Map<String,dynamic> user1 = doc1.data()!;
    Map<String,dynamic> user2 = doc2.data()!;
```